# (C) Segmentation Fault/Error (11) ? How do I find the cause?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

Are segmentation errors caused by Accessing arrays out of bounds? or is it something to do with accessing pointers? I don't think I have reached outside the array. What could it be?

```
char *files[300][300];
char *rebuildFile[300];
int rebuildCount = 0;

void rebuildCheck(){
int i, j;

for(i=1; i<300; i++){
    char * target;
    time_t targetCreationDate = time(NULL);

    for(j=0; j<300; j++){
        if(j==0){
            target = files[i][j];
            char * targetPath = pathAppend(files[i][j]);
            targetCreationDate = getFileCreationTime(targetPath);
        }
        else if(files[i][j] == NULL){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            char * path = pathAppend(files[i][j]);
            time_t dependancyCreationDate = getFileCreationTime(path);
            if(difftime(dependancyCreationDate, targetCreationDate) > 0){
                rebuildFile[rebuildCount] = files[i][j];
                printf("rebuildFile[%i]: %s\n", rebuildCount, rebuildFile[rebuildCount]);
                ++rebuildCount;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: _I don't think I have reached outside the array_... why dont you check this by adding some code? Also consider using a debugger which will tell you _where exactly_  the segfault happens.

Comment: How/where do you initialize all elements of `files`?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and show us the `pathAppend` function. The problem might be _there_. `pathAppend` returns a pointer to a string, many things can go wrong here. But without seeing that code, nobody can tell. Also you didn't show us how `files` is initialized, many things can go wronh there too, maybe one of the char pointers is `NULL`, this could explain a segmentation fault

Comment: @Jabberwocky THANKYOU! yes indeed, pathAppend returned a NULL char pointer value so it mucked up the code.

Comment: @NickWalters still [edit] your question and show the function, there might be other problems you're not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `rebuildCount` is incremented in the inner `for` loop, which means it can potentially go upto 300 * 300.

Then the following statement:

```
rebuildFile[rebuildCount] = files[i][j];
```

will end up accessing an out-of-bounds memory because `rebuildFile` has only 300 elements in it.

Comment: One can never be sure. Since you are printing it, what is the value it reaches before the exception happens?

Comment: the final value of rebuildCount for my program is 5. So that shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: Are you checking pointers like targetPath before using them as arguments? Accessing a invalid pointer also can cause exceptions.